# Show $f(x)=\int_E x^tg(t)d\mu(t)$ is continuous when $\mu$ is a general measure

Tags: measure-theory

Define the function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
 f(x)=\int_E x^tg(t)d\mu(t)
$$
where $E \subset \mathbb{R^+}$,
$\mu$ is a nonnegative measure on $\mathbb{R}$ 
and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $\mu$-integrable function, that is $\int |g|d\mu < \infty$.
Is $f$ a continuous function of $x$?

I would be tempt to use the relation between absolute continuity and the lebesgue integral
but as the measure is not Lebesgue, it's of no use.
Is it possible to show that $f$ is continuous?
Does this need any extra assumptions?

Comment: Is it an identity function multiplied by $\int_{E} g(t) d\mu(t)$?

Comment: This is just $f(x) =c x$, where $c$ is the integral above (with $x=1$).

Comment: @Nimza Good eyes, I should have wrote $x^t$, not $x$. Thank you.

Comment: @copper.hat I meant the integral of $x^t$, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the dominated convergence theorem noting that $|x^t g(t)| \leq |g(t)|$, when $x\in [0,1]$. Then if $x_n\to \hat{x}$, you will have $x_n^t \to \hat{x}^t$, hence $f(x_n) \to f(\hat{x})$. Since this is true for all such sequences, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: What if every $t\in E$ is negative?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Good point. I forgot to mention that the $t$ are positive. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem. We just need to show sequential continuity. Let $x\in [0,1]$ and $\{x_n\}\subset [0,1]$ a sequence which converges to $x$. Let $g_n(t):=x_n^tg(t)$. Then $g_n$ is integrable, $g_n(t)\to x^tg(t)$ for all $t\in E$ and $|g_n(t)|\leq |g(t)|$, which is supposed to be integrable.

Comment: Both your answer and the one of copper.hat are excellent. I throw a coin to decide the winner.

Comment: Luck of the Irish...